# Je suis développeur de chez Capgemini ou je suis développeur chez Capgemini

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, articles, absence-d-article, appositions

Bonjour,

Imaginons le scénario suivant:

je dois envoyer un email à une entreprise qui s'appelle DocTop pour me renseigner au nom de mon entreprise Capgemini.

Je ne sais pas si cette introduction est grammaticalement correcte:

> Bonjour,
>
> Je me présente, je suis Raoul, développeur de chez Capgemini et j'aimerais ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vous avez les possibilités suivantes ;

- Je me présente, je m'appelle Raoul¹, *développeur  chez Capgemini*, et j'aimerais …
- Je me présente, je m'appelle Raoul¹, *un développeur chez Capgemini*, et j'aimerais …
- Je me présente, je m'appelle Raoul¹, *un des développeurs chez Capgemini*, et j'aimerais …
- Je me présente, je m'appelle Raoul¹, *un des développeurs de chez Capgemini*, et j'aimerais …

Dans tous les cas il est recommandé de placer l'expression entre virgules, ce qui est la marque des expressions utilisées *en apposition*.

**Précisions supplémentaires**

« De chez » est une possibilité certaine lorsque l'on utilise un article avec le nom qui précède ; ces ngrams en sont la confirmation : [ngram1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=un+*+de+chez&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cun%20%2A%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bun%20homme%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bun%20jour%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bun%20paysan%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bun%20ouvrier%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bun%20peu%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bun%20proverbe%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bun%20%C3%A9crivain%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bun%20matin%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bun%20apprenti%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bun%20gars%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cun%20*%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bun%20homme%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bun%20jour%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bun%20paysan%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bun%20ouvrier%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bun%20peu%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bun%20proverbe%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bun%20%C3%A9crivain%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bun%20matin%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bun%20apprenti%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bun%20gars%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0), [ngram2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=le+*+de+chez&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cle%20%2A%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ble%20chemin%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20chasser%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20c%C3%B4t%C3%A9%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20matin%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20paysan%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20d%C3%A9part%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20peuple%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20chassa%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20soir%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20C%C3%B4t%C3%A9%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cle%20*%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ble%20chemin%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20chasser%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20c%C3%B4t%C3%A9%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20matin%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20paysan%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20d%C3%A9part%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20peuple%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20chassa%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20soir%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ble%20C%C3%B4t%C3%A9%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0), [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=des+*+de+chez&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cdes%20%2A%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdes%20gens%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdes%20hommes%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdes%20choses%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdes%20nouvelles%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdes%20femmes%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdes%20ouvriers%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdes%20paysans%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdes%20travailleurs%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdes%20noms%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdes%20gars%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cdes%20*%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdes%20gens%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdes%20hommes%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdes%20choses%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdes%20nouvelles%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdes%20femmes%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdes%20ouvriers%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdes%20paysans%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdes%20travailleurs%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdes%20noms%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdes%20gars%20de%20chez%3B%2Cc0), etc. Dans ces cas-là on comprend « un/des/ individu(s) **parmi** (rendu par « de ») ceux chez » ou « l'/les individu(s) **qui sont** (rendu par « de ») chez…».

Lorsque aucun article n'est utilisé, comme le dit une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/37644/17649), l'usage de deux prépositions est plutôt bizarre : on ne spécifie pas deux relations en même temps pour un seul nom (ici « Capgemini » en ajoutant une préposition de plus. On ne fait pas cela à moins de les relier par une conjonction de coordination :

- Cela a été fait avec ou par Julien.
- Cela a été fait pour et par Julien.

On trouve par exemple « du côté de chez » mais c'est analysé comme étant une unité signifiant « près de la demeure de ». On en trouve une autre, « de par chez nous » où trois prépositions se suivent ;  elle est d'un registre très familier ou populaire, et l'analyse est encore celle d'une unique unité signifiant simplement « chez nous » ; ceci montre incidemment que l'empilement de prépositions n'ajoute pas de relation; il n'y en a qu'une, dont le sens est  « près » (premier cas) et  « chez » (second).

¹<sub>Le changement de « je suis » pour « je m'appelle » a été fait suite au rappel dû à cette [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/37656/17649) que « je suis » suivi du prénom ou du patronyme est un anglicisme dans le présent contexte. (Il existe d'autres contextes où la forme convient mais ils sont comparativement rares.)</sub>

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse. Cependant, j'ai souvent entendu mes collègues français de France dire `de chez`, est-ce que c'est correcte de l'utiliser? Ou c'est préférable d'utiliser juste `chez`?

Comment: @smarber J'ai apporté quelques précisions à ma réponse concernant cela.

Comment: *Je me présente, je suis Raoul, un des développeurs chez Capgemini*. Ils vont bien rire chez DocTop...

Comment: @jlliagre aie aie, pourquoi dites-vous ça? Le mail est déjà parti :'(

Comment: Quelle était la formulation de ton mail ? LPH a corrigé *je suis Raoul* après avoir lu ma réponse. Ce n'est pas très grave, les mauvais doublages commencent à populariser *je suis xxx*. La forme *je suis prénom nom* est d'ailleurs possible dans certains cas (les personnes connaissent ton nom mais pas ton visage et tu te présentes à eux en personne), il y a aussi *je suis Charlie*. La prochaine fois, attend plus longtemps avant d'accepter une réponse, surtout de LPH qui manque clairement d'expérience pratique du français et écrit souvent des énormités ou au moins des tournures peu idiomatiques.

Comment: Bien que je sois complètement d'accord avec l'usage grammatical des phrases données en exemple, certaines seraient vraiment étranges si on les utilisait pour se présenter de cette façon.

Comment: @Quidam Je suppose que vous voulez dire qu'en français on n'utiliserait pas seulement le prénom lorsqu'on se présente mais le nom complet (prénom et nom *ou* monsieur et nom); autrement à quoi pensez-vous ?

Comment: Non, je ne trouve pas très naturel de dire "Je me présente, je m'appelle Raoul, un des développeurs de chez Capgemini,", c'est tellement formel que je n'imagine ce genre de phrase que "Je m'appelle Raoul, un des laquets du prince". Dans la réalité, on irait plus vite au but, et on éviterait de paraître trop ampoulé. Mais une fois encore, je ne dis pas que ce n'est pas grammaticalement parfaitement correct, ça dépend juste du contexte. Et dans la programmation, ce n'est pas trop ce genre de culture.

Comment: @Quidam je suis tout à fait d'accord, étant dans le domaine, on a plutôt tendance à aller droit au but. Lorsqu'on se présente, il s'agît d'une seule et même phrase que l'on ne mélange pas avec la suite; le `, et` serait par conséquent supprimé pour pouvoir recommencer une nouvelle phrase. Le genre de phrase de présentation ressemblerai donc à `Bonjour, je m'appelle Raoul, développeur chez CapGemini. J'aimerais ...` (car oui, il faut toujours saluer son interlocuteur, rendant inutile le `Je me présente`)

Comment: @LPH je ne pouvais pas te mentionner dans le même commentaire aussi, l'argumentation devrait t’intéresser

Answer (score 7):

« De » indique la provenance, par ex: Je suis de Lille.
« Chez » indiquerait plutôt une position, par ex: je suis chez moi;

« De + Chez » me parait plutôt bizarre comme formulation. Cela dit, ce n'est que mon avis.

Tu pourrais dire:
- Je suis développeur [travaillant] chez Capgemini
- Je suis un développeur [issu] de Capgemini

Comment: Il n'est pas question de provenance dans le cas présent, comme Capgemini est une société et pas une école et c'est donc seulement d'appartenance qu'il s'agit; donc « issu » ne convient pas bien.

Comment: @LPH Le fait que Capgemini soit une entreprise n'interdit pas la formule. « Issu de + *nom d'entreprise* » est une formulation très courante. On peut très bien "provenir" d'une entreprise, comme on peut le faire d'une école. Ex: [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freescale_Semiconductor) : Michel Mayer, un industriel français issu d'IBM, prend le poste de président-directeur général à la création de Freescale.

Comment: @jlliagre Vous diriez donc « Michel Mayer, un industriel français provenant d'IBM,» ? Il me semble qu'il s'agit d'un nouvel usage ou d'un manque d'idiomatisme, bien que je n'en soit pas sûr ; J'ai bien vu quelque chose comme « président du conseil issu du Parlement » mais il me semblait qu'il faille une sorte de filière, une analogie avec l'idée de produit par descendance (issu de l'agriculture biologique, par exemple).

Comment: @LPH Bien sûr. Pourquoi ne dirais-je pas *provenant d'IBM* si c'est de là qu'il vient ?

Comment: @jlliagre « Provenir » signifie « venir de », mais dans le sens de « avoir pour origine » et cela semble aussi bizarre ; apparemment on n'attache pas l'idée d'origine aux sociétés et firmes en parlant de ceux qu'elles emploient mais plutôt l'idée d'appartenance. Il doit s'agir d'un nouveau point de vue qui tendrait à souligner que les firmes constituent des « écoles » à leur manière.

Answer (score 4):

Rien n'interdit d'utiliser l'expression « de chez + *nom de société* », même si elle est plus du domaine du langage parlé.

Par exemple: [Guide pratique des réseaux Windows - Eyrolles](https://www.eyrolles.com/Informatique/Livre/guide-pratique-des-reseaux-windows-9782844270702/)

> Ce guide pratique répond à toutes ces questions. Un livre sans équivalent, signé par un ancien développeur de chez Microsoft.

Il est cependant rare d'utiliser *de chez* quand on parle de soi.

Deux remarques hors sujet pour ce qui est de l'introduction:

1. Inutile de dire qu'on se présente, c'est une évidence.
2. *Je suis Raoul* est un anglicisme. En français on dira *Je m'appelle Raoul*.

Je suggérerais donc :

> Bonjour,
>
> Je m'appelle Raoul et je suis développeur chez Capgemini. J'aimerais...

Comment: Je suis arrivée en venant de chez moi en retard. C'est le verbe qui régit la preposition **de**, n'est-ce pas?

Comment: @Lambie Ça  n'a pas de lien avec la question. Il n'y a pas de verbe dans *développeur de chez Capgemini*

Comment: Justement, parce que c'est un verbe qui régirait l'utilisation de la preposition. Vous dites "de chez [nom]" et moi j'ai ajouté qu'il faut un verbe si on va l'utiliser. Oú le mal?

Comment: @Lambie Désolé, mais je ne comprends pas où tu veux en venir. Je ne vois pas comment quelque chose qui peut être absent pourrait régir quoi que ce soit.

Answer (score 2):

Vous pouvez dire "développeur pour Cap Gemini" ou "développeur de Cap Gemini" car c'est une SSII qui fournit des prestations. C'est d'autant plus vrai une fois chez le client. Dire que vous êtes développeur chez Cap Gemini, c'est plutôt pour le bureau d'études. En aucun cas "de chez".

Comment: Développeur pour Cap Gemini" aurait un sens complètement différent. ça fait référence à une relation de sous-traitance.

Answer (score -1):

On peut travailler "chez Renault" parce qu'il s'agit à l'origine d'une personne : "chez Louis Renault". Il n'existe pas de monsieur Cap Gemini, donc "chez Cap Gemini" n'est pas logique (mais très courant).

Comment: *Maison X* a longtemps été utilisé pour désigner une entreprise, que son nom soit le nom du patron/fondateur ou pas. Il n'y a donc rien d'illogique a dire *chez Mercedes, chez Google, chez Orange, chez Free, chez EDF, etc*

Comment: Je ne suis pas d'accord avec cette réponse, il ne s'agit pas de personnes, mais de marques. Les marques autrefois étaient appelées des "maisons". Je travaille pour la maison Cartier, la maison Untel. On peut toujours dire "chez" quand on cite une marque, qu'elle soit à l'origine un nom ou pas n'y change rien.

Answer (score -2):

Comme le fait justement remarquer Mathieu Bouville, chez ne s'écrit que devant le nom d'un être animé. Du moins, si l'on en croit [*Larousse*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/chez/15246#difficulte). Toutefois, il est très courant de dire "travailler chez (une entreprise)" et ce, que ce soit le nom d'une personne (vivante ou ayant vécu) ou pas. Travailler chez *Apple* est possible et pour preuve: [Travailler chez Apple](https://www.apple.com/jobs/fr/). M. Apple serait ravi de vous accueillir au sein de son équipe.. Je peux aussi travailler chez *Naturalia*, *Amazon*, etc.

De plus, *Larousse* nous fait remarquer qu'au niveau construction, **chez** peut être utilisé avec une préposition. Il me semble que **de** entre dans cette catégorie. Nous pouvons donc dire que **de chez** est correct.

Toutefois, et ceci est mon ressenti, **de chez** est du registre familier. En aucun cas, je ne le mettrais dans une lettre de motivation.

Il y a une expression familière avec "de chez" :

> Bien de chez nous (typique du milieu auquel on appartient)

Dans une conversation non formelle, citant un de mes collègues, je pourrais dire

> C'est un développeur d' chez nous

Ensuite, devant un nom attribut indiquant une profession, il n'y a normalement pas de déterminant. La raison étant que la profession ici est comparable à un adjectif. Donc, comme tu l'as écrit, c'est très bien (et même mieux).

> Je m'appelle Raoul, (je suis) développeur chez Capgemini, ...

Comment: Pardon, mais c'est faux. On travaille comme ça chez Monoprix ou chez Cartier. Il n'y a pas de différence. Le "chez" veut dire à l'origine "La maison Untel", où Untel est le nom de la marque, un patronyme à l'origine, ou n'importe quel nom fabriqué, a ne change rien.