# « La demande à Uber » ou « La demande chez Uber »?

Tags: prépositions

> Le temps d’attente avant notre prise en charge par un chauffeur sera en fonction de la demande à Uber.

> Le temps d’attente avant notre prise en charge par un chauffeur sera en fonction de la demande chez Uber.

L’usage dit qu’on devrait privilégier l’utilisation de la préposition « à » devant un générique suivi d’un spécifique et « chez » devant un patronyme, mais qu’en est-il devant le nom d’une entreprise explicitement nommée, comme Uber, qui n’est pas un patronyme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On considère Uber comme une "maison" avec le sens qui devient désuet d'entreprise commerciale ou industrielle ([TLFi **B. - 4.**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/maison)). La préposition sera donc *chez* :

> Le temps d’attente avant notre prise en charge par un chauffeur **sera fonction**(/dépendra) de la demande **chez** Uber.

Voir aussi : [Je suis développeur de chez Capgemini ou je suis développeur chez Capgemini](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/37643)

Comment: Devant Hydro-Québec et Air Canada, quelle préposition emploierais-tu?

Comment: https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/index.php?id=21593

Comment: Oui, les deux et probablement plus souvent *à* pour un service public. Toujours *à/au* si c'est un nom/signe qui prend un article (*à la SNCF, à la préfecture, au ministère de l'intérieur*). Peut-être que ma préférence pour ***chez Uber*** est due aussi au fait que ça se prononce exactement comme ***chez Hubert*** :-)